# RVM with Dual HD and "space in name" error

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, hardware

I have two development machines, both running Mac OS Mountain Lion. One the desktop I have to HD's installed (applications and system installed on an SD and user account on a standard.) On this machine, when I go to install RVM, it says something about being a lucky "space in user name" user and that I need to add some special links or whatnot. Those methods then lead to their own host of bugs. My question is, what is it about having my usr/local on one hd and my User account on another would lead to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as [motleydev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053260/motleydev), and the spaces turned out to be a red herring. Instead, it appears that the RVM script is hardcoding "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" somewhere. I concluded this by the following experiment:

I had two partitions, the original ("Macintosh HD") and the new one I was working on ("Macintosh HD Rawr"). *(When making my rawr partition, I had assumed spaces were okay in partition names, since clearly Macintosh HD has always worked for me before)*

Initial error when running `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484 --verify-downloads 1:`

```
/bin/sh: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
make: *** [enc] Error 127
```

When I tried renaming "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ Rawr" to be "/Volumes/Macintosh" (I renamed via Finder, which leaves the symlink `/Volumes/Macintosh -> /` intact), the installation still failed, but with a different error:

```
/bin/sh: /Volumes/Macintosh: source: no such file or directory
make: *** [enc] Error 127
```

I then renamed my old volume from "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD" to be "/Volumes/MacintoshHD", and the installation was still failing, but now I was getting different errors:

```
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/opt/twitter/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-opt-dir=/opt/twitter/opt/libyaml:/opt/twitter/opt/readline:/opt/twitter/opt/libksba:/opt/twitter/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/opt/twitter/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Looking at the config.log, I found the following error:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change
```

Since neither volume was named "Macintosh HD" at this time, this indicates that this has been hardcoded somewhere in the RVM code.

Sure enough, changing my desired partition to "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD" allowed the rvm to finish its business.

Comment: It could be that the script grabs the path from xcode-select.  I wasn't satisfied with changing my partition name as a solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I always assume that most tools do not understand spaces in names, so my usernames never contain spaces. Compare these two lines, for example (those are real names from my setup)

```
source /Volumes/MySSD/Users/sergio/.rvm/scripts/rvm
source /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/sergio/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

The second line will fail with message "source: no such file or directory: /Volumes/Macintosh", because it interprets this path as two arguments, separated by space. To make it work, you have to enclose the path in quotes (or escape the space with a backslash). As far as I remember, RVM scripts contain one or two commands where paths are not quoted. I had to deal with those myself, when I was migrating to dual disk setup. I can't remember the details now, but this is likely the source of your problems, paths being incorrectly interpreted.

Comment: you are right that rvm does not quote paths, but there is more to this - it's hundreds of lines not quoted + additional load of `eval` statements that require additional quote escaping, fixing it all at once would be quite huge effort compared to using the link. This will be properly handled in RVM 2.x where we will use totally new code and most of the core functions will be provided from [SM Framewok](https://github.com/sm/sm)

Comment: I understand the escaping issue - but on my Laptop, with 'Macintosh HD' the install works just fine - on the desktop, where two hd's exist - I then get the problem. That's where I am confused. No link was needed on my laptop it worked just fine - and I was assuming that "user" was refering to the particular user account at hand - not the whole string. Is it possible that wth the path change I need to point it to the secondary HD? I think that's where it's loading the .rvm dir which is not the same place my user account is. How would I modify the echo path to point to a secondary hd properly?

Answer (score 0):

#### Just follow the instructions:

It looks you are one of the happy *space* users(in home dir name),
RVM is not yet fully ready for it, use this trick to fix it:

```
sudo ln -s "$HOME/.rvm/" /$USER.rvm
echo "export rvm_path=/$USER.rvm" >> "$HOME/.rvmrc"
```

and start installing again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar dual-hd situation:

It may be because xcode-select is not selecting the proper application.
Checking the help for xcode-select, you'll see that you can reset the application it selects to a system default like this:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

Or, if you already know the location of the XCode you want to use something like this:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

xcode-select documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html